# Understanding a dual space example: $(l_p)^*\equiv l_q$ where $1/p+1/q=1$

Tags: real-analysis, duality-theorems

I am trying to understand dual spaces in real analysis. Let's look at the following:

> Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and 
>   $$l_p:=\left\{ x=\{x_n\}\ |\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|x_n|^p <\infty\right\}\quad  \text{with norm}\quad \|x\|_p:=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|x_n|^p\right)^{1/p}$$
>   and
>   $$l_{\infty}:=\left\{ x=\{x_n\}\ |\ \sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|x_n| <\infty\right\}\quad  \text{with norm}\quad \|x\|_{\infty}:=\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|x_n|.$$
>   Then it follows that
>
> $(l_p)^*\equiv l_q$ where $1/p+1/q=1$ with $q=\infty$ when $p=1$.

I think it's safe to assume that $^*$ represents the dual space and $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence.

As I understand it, the dual space of $l_p$ is the set of maps $(l_p,\|\cdot\|_p)\to(\mathbb R, |\cdot|)$. This set can be thought of as a set of relations between $l_p$ and $\mathbb R$, so each element in $(l_p)^*$ is a relation.

Now, $l_q$ where $1/p+1/q=1$ is a set $\left\{ \{x_n\}\ |\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|x_n|^q <\infty\right\}$. I don't see how the elements of this set, which are infinite sequences, can be relations.

Can you please explain the conclusion?

Comment: This is a common abuse of notation. The dual space of $\ell^p$ is isomorphic to $\ell^q$. Please refer to any book where this theory is developed. See also Wikipedia for a quick introduction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Dual_spaces

Comment: @Siminore I haven't got a textbook to study this, only the lecturer's notes.

Comment: What textbook do you recommend for this?

Comment: My favorite is an old texbook by Larsen. The title is "Functional Analysis". But many textbooks offer a proof of this fact.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X = (x_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\ell^p$.  Let $Y = (y_n)_{n\in\Bbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $\ell^q$.  We reinterpret $(y_n)$ as a map in $(\ell^p)^*$ via $Y(X) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{N}} x_n y_n$, yielding a map $Y:\ell^p \rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$, as needed.